# How does libtool decide to build a shared library or not?

Tags: dynamic-linking, libtool

How does libtool decide to build a shared library or not?

Chenz

Answer (score 1):

If you use Automake and Autoconf, then Libtool builds both shared and static by default if they are supported on your platform. To build only one kind, call `configure` with `--disable-static` or `--disable-shared`.

Comment: but how does it determine if your setup supports shared or static linking?

Comment: Including the `LT_INIT` macro (or `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL` on old versions) in your `configure.ac` makes it check what your system supports at configure-time.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/libtool/

> Libtool can create either dynamically 
>   linked  shared  libraries,  with
>          **-dynamic**, or statically linked (archive) libraries, with
>   **-static**.